# Mongoosejs: how to pass node validator object to the callback function of a query

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I'm struggling for a while trying to pass variables/functions to a mongoose query callback function.

What I'm trying to do is:
**EDIT:** title changed and example redefined

```
Validator.protoptype.customCheck = function(model, path) {

  var self = this // validator object {msg: 'msg', error: ...};

  model.find({name: 'john'}, function(err, res) {
    if (res.length === 0) {
      self.error( self.msg ) // msg hasn't the expected value. 
      // As I have some other validators after this callback gets executed
      // the context is different. don't know how to pass the right context
    } else {
      // something else ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: To give more details, the real context I want to use this is to make a custom validator for [node-validator](https://github.com/chriso/node-validator#extending-the-library) to check the uniqueness of a value.

Comment: You can call `myvar` there just fine; what's the specific problem you're seeing?

Comment: @JohnnyHK: You're right, in fact I try to pass `this` from the custom 'Validator' function. the problem is that the context changes (another validator is called in between) before the callback is executed ... I'm totally lost. If you need a more precise example of what I want to do, thanks to tell me.

Comment: Your synchronous `customCheck` validation function will have already returned by the time the async `find` callback occurs, so by then the validator object is no longer valid.

Comment: Yes I just realized that. Damn! I thought about this at some time, any idea/resource on how to make synchronous query?

Comment: You can't.  You need to use something that supports async.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support. I'll check that side.